How can I get html node values in json array dynamically
I want to get these inputs  for n person. So I should wrote the code better but as I'm newbie I don't know how I can do this.
my inputs that the user fill in jsp file:
 {
   "name":"Jones",
   "lastname":" Smith",
   "email":"smith@a.com",
   "gender":"Male",
   "age": 28,
   "address":
   {
    "streetaddress":"724th Street",
    "city":"New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalcode":"10038"
   }
  },

  {
   "name":"Jack",
   "lastname":" farmer",
   "email":"farmer@a.com",
   "gender":"Male",
   "age": 32,
   "address":
   {
    "streetaddress":"121th Street",
    "city":"New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalcode":"10045"
   }
 }

register.jsp
.
.
. 
<input> ...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register").click(function() {
        // get inputs
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var gender = $('#gender').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        var streetaddress = $('#streetaddress').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();
        var state = $('#state').val();
        var postalcode = $('#postalcode').val();
    
        var myVar = JSON.stringify({
                name: firstname,
                lastname: lastname,
                email:email,
                gender:gender,
                age:age,
                "Address":[
                    {
                        streetaddress:streetaddress,
                        city:city,
                        state:state,
                        postalcode:postalcode
                    }],
            });
            alert(myVar);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/UserController',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'params=' + myVar,//sending json data
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    //just for printing purpose
                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert("Success ...");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
  </script>
.

UserController.java
@WebServlet(name = "UserController", value = "/userController",urlPatterns = 
{"/register"})
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   User data = gson.fromJson(params, User.class);
   Address address = new Address(data.getAddress().streetaddress(),
            data.getAddress().getCity(),
            data.getAddress().getState(),
            data.getAddress().postalcode());

   User user = new User(data.getName(),
            data.getLastName(),
            data.getEmail(),
            data.getGender(),
            data.getAge(),
            data.getAddress());

User.java
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String email;
@Embedded
private Address address;
@Column(name = "gender")
private String gender;
@Column(name = "age")
private int age;

public User(String name,
            String lastName,
            String email,
            Address address,
            String gender,
            int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}
... setter and getter

I want my code to be a bit more advanced. For this purpose, I want all the inputs in the JS file to be dynamically put in an array and read in the controller. Since I have little knowledge about this matter, please help me in learning.(in for array in index 0 get names, index1 get lastname, ...)
For example:
const myArr = [];
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    myObj[i].firstname= $('#firstname').val();
    myObj[i].lastname= $('#lastname').val();
    myObj[i].email=$('#email').val();
    myObj[i].password1=$('#password1').val();
    myObj[i].password2=$('#password2').val();

    myArr.push(myobj)
 }

How can I add address to this array?

Show more of the JSON data and show the User class.

@ SedJ601  I added some extra details

The dynamic JSON data might be a pain when you need to convert JSON object to Java. This answer may help you to write JSON dynamically.

The first thing that I noticed is that your JSON is not valid as is. I have altered your JSON to make it valid. To get the Nth user, you need to get the JSON into an Array or List.
Key Code
Gson gson = new Gson();
User[] users = gson.fromJson(getFileContent(), User[].class);

Main
import com.google.gson.Gson;


/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaTestingArea {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        User[] users = gson.fromJson(getFileContent(), User[].class);
        
        for(User user : users)
        {
            System.out.println(user.getId());
            System.out.println(user.getName());
            System.out.println(user.getAge());
            System.out.println(user.getAddress().getCity());
            System.out.println(user.getAddress().getStreetAddress());
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        //To get an Nth user
        System.out.println("Nth user info.");
        User user = users[1];
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getAge());
        System.out.println(user.getAddress().getCity());
        System.out.println(user.getAddress().getStreetAddress());        
}  
    
    static public String getFileContent()
    {
        return """
               [
                   {
                       "name": "Jones",
                       "lastname": " Smith",
                       "email": "smith@a.com",
                       "gender": "Male",
                       "age": 28,
                       "address": {
                           "streetaddress": "724th Street",
                           "city": "New York",
                           "state": "NY",
                           "postalcode": "10038"
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       "name": "Jack",
                       "lastname": " farmer",
                       "email": "farmer@a.com",
                       "gender": "Male",
                       "age": 32,
                       "address": {
                           "streetaddress": "121th Street",
                           "city": "New York",
                           "state": "NY",
                           "postalcode": "10045"
                       }
                   }
               ]
               """;
    }
}

User
public class User
{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
    private String gender;
    private int age;

    public User(long id, String name, String email, Address address, String gender, int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("User{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", name=").append(name);
        sb.append(", email=").append(email);
        sb.append(", address=").append(address);
        sb.append(", gender=").append(gender);
        sb.append(", age=").append(age);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }    
}

Address
public class Address
{
    private String streetaddress;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalcode;

    public Address(String streetaddress, String city, String state, String postalcode)
    {
        this.streetaddress = streetaddress;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postalcode = postalcode;
    }

    public String getPostalcode()
    {
        return postalcode;
    }

    public void setPostalcode(String postalcode)
    {
        this.postalcode = postalcode;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress()
    {
        return streetaddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetaddress)
    {
        this.streetaddress = streetaddress;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Address{");
        sb.append("streetaddress=").append(streetaddress);
        sb.append(", city=").append(city);
        sb.append(", state=").append(state);
        sb.append(", postalcode=").append(postalcode);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

Output
0
Jones
28
New York
724th Street

0
Jack
32
New York
121th Street

Nth user info.
0
Jack
32
New York
121th Street


Thank you for reply. In the Main section you wrote, I want the code in javascript because the user enter his personal information in the register form. Ho w can I wrote it?

Are you using Spring or something? I am not familiar with that. I am not sure why you are focused on getting the Nth user here. In your code, you are getting the user's info and registering them. My guess is that your JSON should only have one user in the situation.

just java ee. I will have to expand the code later. In addition, the speed of work is faster when many users register with this method. Now my problem is that I can't get all the nodes in the presentation, in fact I don't know
